# Parsing "clusters" of lines in a text file based on number of lines below a word in python

Tags: python, file, parsing, search, count

So I have a uniformly formatted text file that I am trying to parse based on the number of lines below the word 'cluster'. Here is my code so far:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
main_output = open('mainoutput.txt', 'w')
minor_output = open('minoroutput.txt', 'w')
f_lines = f.readlines()
main_list = []
minor_list = []
for n, line in enumerate(open('file.txt')):
    if 'cluster' in line:
        if 'cluster' in f_lines[n+1] or f_lines[n+2] or f_lines[n+3]:
            minor_list.append(line)
            minor_list.append(f_lines[n+1])
            minor_list.append(f_lines[n+2])
            minor_list.append(f_lines[n+3])
        if 'cluster' not in f_lines[n+1] or f_lines[n+2] or f_lines[n+3]:
            main_list.append(line)
            main_list.append(f_lines[n+1])
            main_list.append(f_lines[n+2])
            main_list.append(f_lines[n+3])
minor_output.write(''.join(minor_list))
main_output.write(''.join(main_list))
f.close()
main_output.close()
minor_output.close()
```

The format of the text file is as follows:

```
>Cluster 1
line 1
line 2
line 3
...

>Cluster 2
line 1
line 2
...

and so on for many clusters.
```

Each cluster has a variable number of lines below it, from 1 to 100+. I am interested in sorting these clusters by the number of lines(items) in each cluster. This code is working but the two output files are identical. Any help with my code or my strategy would be awesome!

Comment: How do you want the output to be formatted?

Comment: preferably in the same format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the code you've posted correctly, you want to sort your data into two different files depending on how many items are in a cluster. If there are three or fewer, the cluster goes into `minoroutput.txt`, while if there are more than that, it goes into `mainoutput.txt`.

There are a couple of significant logic errors that I suspect are causing your code to not sort the data properly.

Firstly, your test to see if an line contains the word `"cluster"` won't match capitalized `"Cluster"` like you have in your example data. This may only be an issue with the example data you've shown, and it's would be easy to fix by calling `lower()` on the line before checking it.

Second, your check of later lines is incorrect. The code `if 'cluster' in f_lines[n+1] or f_lines[n+2] or f_lines[n+3]` doesn't check for `"cluster"` in each of the three strings, but rather only in the first. The second and third strings are being evaluated all by themselves, in boolean context. If they're not empty lines, they'll be `True`, making the whole expression almost always true as well. For this to work, you'd need to check `'cluster' in f_lines[n+1] or 'cluster' in f_lines[n+2] or 'cluster' in f_lines[n+3]` (but I'll show a better alternative later). The same problem happens with the other `if` statement, where you will also almost always get a `True` result from your condition, since `f_lines[n+2]` and `f_lines[n+3]` are probably not both empty.

Lastly, your logic for writing out the clusters is probably incorrect. It currently writes out exactly four lines always, even though many clusters will have more or fewer items than that. For every cluster written to `mainoutput.txt`, some lines will be discarded (this might be deliberate). For some cluster's written to `minoroutupt.txt`, however, there's going to be a clear bug where it will write out the start of the next cluster after a cluster with only one or two items.

Here's some code that I think will work for you. I've changed around the loop so that it just reads the file once, rather than reading the lines once into a list and a second time in `enumerate`. Rather than explicitly looking at the next three lines, I simply put each line into a list, resetting each time there's a line with `cluster` in it (with any capitalization).

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f, \
     open('mainoutput.txt', 'w') as main_out, \
     open('minoroutput.txt', 'w') as minor_out:
    cluster = [] # this variable will hold all the lines of the current cluster
    for line in f:
        if 'cluster' in line.lower(): # if we're at the start of a cluster
            if len(cluster) > 4: # long clusters go in the "main" file
                main_out.writelines(cluster) # write out the lines
                # main_out.writelines(cluster[:4])
            else:
                minor_out.writelines(cluster) # or to the other file

            cluster = [] # reset the cluster variable to a new, empty list

        cluster.append(line) # always add the current line to cluster

    if len(cluster) > 4: # repeat the writing logic for the last cluster
        main_out.writelines(cluster)
        # main_out.writelines(cluster[:4])
    else:
        minor_out.writelines(cluster)
```

Use the two commented `writelines` lines in place of the uncommented ones just before them if you only want the first three items in a cluster to be output into `mainout.txt` (with the rest being discarded). I don't think there's a reasonable alternative to printing all the lines in `minorout.txt`.

Given `file.txt` with these contents:

```
>Cluster 1
line 1
line 2
line 3
>Cluster 2
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
>Cluster 3
line 1
>Cluster 4
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

The code above will output two files:

`mainoutput.txt`:

```
>Cluster 2
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
>Cluster 4
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

`minoroutput.txt`:

```
>Cluster 1
line 1
line 2
line 3
>Cluster 3
line 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps tremendously.

Comment: I am very new to python I have only been coding for about 2 weeks now, hence the errors with my original code, I understand what your code is doing but I am having trouble figuring out which part of the code does the "resetting" of the list when it encounters another instance of 'cluster'? If you could explain it would be very helpful.

Comment: The "resetting" I referred to is where I create a new list as `cluster` after the `if`/`else` block. I'll add a few comments to the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! So if I am understanding this correctly; one cluster is being added to a list=> that list is written in the proper output file=> the list is reset=> the next cluster is listed, then added to the output file=> list resets again => and this is repeated... until the file.txt is exhausted?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. There needs to be special handling for the last list in the input file (because the end of other clusters are detected by the start of the next one), which you can see as the repeated `if`/`else` block at the end. The start is probably a little goofy too, as it does a zero-line write to the minor file when the first cluster starts. It's probably possible to design that in a different way, but this seemed to have the simplest code.